# TextView not being displayed / Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, textview

This might seem like a very easy question for some of you folks, but I can't find a way to display my TextView even after trying numerous solutions proposed on this site.  Not that I am using the built-in Eclipse XML tool for Android and that the TextView is visible on this graphical layout.  Here's what I've got so far :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/no_of_screens"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewHome"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="212dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/launch_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:text="@string/launch" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/launch_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/launch_button"
        android:entries="@array/num_array"
        android:prompt="@string/screen_prompt"
        android:textSize="8pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/launch_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/launch_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:text="@string/no_of_screens"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As for now, all of the other elements are being displayed correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is the Res of the Graphical Editor the same as the device you are testing on?

Comment: I have tested your layout and it works fine, your error must be somewhere else in your program, check where you set the value of the TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want your textView?

I would loose these two:

`layout_alignBaseline="@+id/launch_button`

`layout_alignBottom="@+id/launch_button`

and use one of these:

`layout_below="@+id/launch_button`

`layout_above="@+id/launch_button`

That will put it either above or below the button.

Comment: This did the trick actually but I don't really know why.  Anyway, thanks for the help!